# If datetimepicker1 is greater than datetimpicker2

Tags: c#

I would like to ask a question :(
I'm already confuse since i want to show a message box that contains "Invalid Date" if  datetimepicker1 is greater than datetimepicker2

Thank you for those who will help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this way:

```
DateTime iDate;
      iDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    DateTime eDate;
      eDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;
    if (iDate > eDate ) {
      MessageBox.Show("Invalid Date.");
    }
```

Comment: @Marvin Retro if the code solves your problem,please accept me as a answer

Comment: It works ! thank you for helping ! sorry for the spoonfeed question since i cant post a picture of my code and im on a rush and using my mobile :V  ! thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (dateTimePicker1.Value > dateTimePicker2.Value ) {
  MessageBox.Show("Invalid Date.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question :D

Answer (score 0):

you Can set the value of `datetimepicker1.MinimumDateTime(datetimepicker2.Value)`
or you can Compare the tow values with each other hope that helps 
:)

**Update**
its the same as the answer i just needed to modify my answer to make it better and generic

```
 DateTime dateOne ;
  dateOne = dateTimePicker1.Value;
DateTime dateTow ;
  dateTow = dateTimePicker2.Value;
if (dateOne > dateTow  ) {console.writeline("Date Number One is Bigger")}
```

else{console.writeline("Date Number tow is Bigger");}

Comment: Thank you for answering my question ! god bless :D